# Laravel 5.1 - public folder issue

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.1, public

I have installed laravel on windows server (using IIS 8.5) and I am having issues removing the public folder from the URL. I managed to make laravel's public folder as my domain's root folder which solved this issue, however, on form submit via ajax I am unable to remove the public folder from the url. For example:

my domain is www.abc.com and I have a form, which on submit needs to post to www.abc.com/login. But I get 404 error if I don't include the public in the url. If I send a ajax request to www.abc.com/public/login, it works perfectly fine.

I also add my web.config files:

```
1. outside public folder( in httpdocs folder)

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <configuration>
            <system.webServer>
                <rewrite>
                  <rules>
                    <rule name="Imported Rule 11" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                  </rules>
                </rewrite>
            </system.webServer>
        </configuration>


    2. inside public folder

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <system.webServer>
            <rewrite>
                <rules>
         <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule> 
                </rules>
            </rewrite>    
        </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I spent 12 hours searching many forums but couldn't get any solution. Any help will be highly appreciated as I am really stuck. Thanks

Comment: which webserver (apache/nginx)?

Comment: Make sure you set the **document root** path for the HTTP server to the `public` directory, meaning it should be `/path/to/laravel-app/public`. This would require you setting up virtual hosts if you are running apache. If you're running another server then please specify which one.

Comment: I am using IIS webserver and have included my web config files as well in the question posted.